# Access constructor value

Tags: c#

I am trying to access value in my code. I have two classes, carex and engine.

The engine class has the following code:

```
public class Engine
{
    public string Size;
    public int HorsePower;
    public float FuelConsumtionRate;
    
    public Engine()
    {
    }
    
    public Engine(string cylinder, int hp, float fuelRate)
    {
        Size = cylinder;
        Console.WriteLine($"Engine type: {cylinder}");
        HorsePower = hp;
        Console.WriteLine($"Horse power: {hp} hp");
        FuelConsumtionRate = fuelRate;
        Console.WriteLine($"Fuel consumption: {fuelRate} l/h");
    }
}
```

The carex class has the following code:

```
public class CarEx
{
    string Manfacturer;
    string RegistrationNr;
    float Fuel;
    float Speed;
    bool IsRunning;
    
    public CarEx(string manuf, float fuel, string regNr)
    {
        Manfacturer = manuf;
        this.Fuel = fuel;
        RegistrationNr = regNr;
        Console.WriteLine("_____________________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine($"Manufacturer; {manuf}, Fuel amount: {fuel}l, License: {regNr}");
        Console.WriteLine("______________________________________________________");
    }
    
    public void ChooseEngineType()
    {
        Engine v4 = new Engine("v4", 200, 0.7f);        
    }

    public void FillFuel(float amount)
    {
        Fuel += amount;
        /*            
        Fuel -= 0.7f;
        */
    }
        
    public static void RunCar()
    {
        CarEx car1 = new CarEx("Saab", 10, "1234DD");
        car1.CallCustomer();
        Console.WriteLine($"Maker: {car1.Manfacturer}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Registration nr: {car1.RegistrationNr}");
    }
}
```

I would like to replace the hard coded fuel consumption rate

> Fuel -= 0.7f;

which I commented out with the value set in the engine constructor so its not hard coded any more.

What am I missing out on?

Comment: what's your problem? you haven't really done enough to communicate a question

Comment: You can access the FuelConsumtionRate variable in Engine because it's  public from CarEx i.e. Fuel -= v4 .FuelConsumtionRate ?

Comment: I would like to acess the fuel rate in the engine constructor and us it instead of the hard coded fuel rate.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ChooseEngineType` method creates an `Engine` object, but it is stored in a local variable which ceases to exist as soon as the method ends.

Change that variable to a field or property `Engine engine` at **class** level, and then you can use `engine` and its property `engine.FuelConsumtionRate` in all methods.

(PS, the proper spelling of that property would be *FuelConsumptionRate*)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the fuel consumption rate is constant, you can use a constant that is privately accessible in the class you've declared by doing this:

```cs
private const float fuelConsumptionRate = 0.7f;
```

and then use it in your code so that you do not hard-code the changes. Otherwise, if the rate is bound to change, you'll need to store either the `Engine` itself (most recommended), or just the consumption rate in a private field like this:

```cs
private Engine engine;
// or
private float fuelConsumptionRate;

// the rest of your class' code
public void ChooseEngineType()
{
    float rate = 0.7f;
    Engine v4 = new Engine("v4", 200, rate);
    engine = v4;
    // or
    fuelConsumptionRate = rate;
}
```

Comment: The fuel rate will differentiate depending of engine. But I will take a look at your suggestion and try it out :)

Comment: Aside from your current issue, I would strongly advise you to store the `Engine` in a private field since it would fit more the logic of your requested implementation. Therefore you should be able to access the fuel consumption rate through the field and even have a property for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Added a new constructor for fuel rate in Engine class

```
public class Engine
        {
            public static string Size;
            public static int HorsePower;
            public static float FuelConsumtionRate;

            //Constructor to set fuel reate
            public Engine(float fuelRate)
            {
                FuelConsumtionRate = fuelRate;
            }
            public Engine(string cylinder, int hp, float fuelRate)
            {
                Size = cylinder;
                Console.WriteLine($"Engine type: {cylinder}");
                HorsePower = hp;
                Console.WriteLine($"Horse power: {hp} hp");
                FuelConsumtionRate = fuelRate;
                Console.WriteLine($"Fuel consumption: {fuelRate} l/h");
            }
```

And in the carex class:

```
public class CarEx
    {
        string Manfacturer { get; set; }
        string RegistrationNr { get; set; }
        float Fuel;
        float Speed;
        bool IsRunning;

        public CarEx(string manuf, float fuel, string regNr)
        {
            Manfacturer = manuf;
            this.Fuel = fuel;
            RegistrationNr = regNr;
            Console.WriteLine("_____________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine($"Manufacturer; {manuf}, Fuel amount: {fuel}l, License: {regNr}");
            Console.WriteLine("______________________________________________________");
        }

        public void ChooseEngineType()
        {
            Engine v4 = new Engine("v4", 200, 0.7f);

        }

public void Accelerate()
        {
Speed += 6.0f;

//Fuel rate set for v4 object
Fuel -= Engine.FuelConsumtionRate;
}
```